# Why calling lifecycleScope.launch { //interact with database } works (without chaging the coroutine context), is a new thread created?

Tags: kotlin, android-room, dao, coroutine

I am confused by why the following code works (called from MainActivity):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    log(Thread.currentThread().name) //main
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        interactWithDatabase()
    }
}

suspend fun interactWithDatabase(){
    log(Thread.currentThread().name) //main
    NoteDatabase(this).getNoteDao().addNote(Note(id=0, title = "TITLE", note = "BODY"))
    //signature of addNote: @Insert suspend fun addNote(note: Note)
    textView.text = "TEST" //making sure I can update the UI
}
```

"main" is printed twice.

If the method addNote is not "suspend-able", I get the following exception:

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
> ```

This leads me to believe that making "addNote" suspend-able means a new thread is created when the method is called. (That's probably not the case, but I can't think of another explanation. If we stayed on the main thread and the main thread worked like a Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), it would still eventually run on the main thread and keep it from calling onDraw correct?)

The following confuses me even more:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    log(Thread.currentThread().name) //main
    lifecycleScope.launch(**Dispatchers.IO**){
        interactWithDatabase()
    }
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
}

suspend fun interactWithDatabase(){
    log(Thread.currentThread().name) //DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    NoteDatabase(this).getNoteDao().addNote(Note(id=0, title = "TITLE", note = "BODY"))
    //signature of addNote: @Insert suspend fun addNote(note: Note)
    textView.text = "TEST" //actually updates the UI
}
```

Why am I allowed to change textView.text from the non-main thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-1"?

Comment: I don’t use Room, but it has you define your functions in an interface and it generates the actual implementation code, right? Almost certainly, if it sees `suspend` in the function signature, it wraps its generated implementation function code in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, internally to the function.

Comment: This is a standard coroutines idiom. All public suspend functions should be designed to be safe to call from the Main Dispatcher, which is most simply accomplished by internally wrapping blocking code in `withContext`.

Comment: As for your second question, not all UI interaction methods do runtime checks to enforce use of the main thread. These calls usually work but will sometimes cause subtle bugs (so don’t do it).

Comment: @Tenfour04 I  tried `Thread(){
            textView.text = "TEST"
            log(Thread.currentThread().name) //Thread-3
        }.start()` and it worked, which confirms what you said. I checked the implementation of RoomDao in the build folder and found a special method CoroutinesRoom.execute which does switch context `val context = coroutineContext[TransactionElement]?.transactionDispatcher
                ?: if (inTransaction) db.transactionDispatcher else db.queryDispatcher
            return withContext(context) {
                callable.call()
            }`